# How to insert record with many to many relational tables

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

work on asp.net mvc5 ef-6.Face problem with many to many relational table data insertion.My classes  models are

```
public class Product
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    //navigation property to Supplier
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSupplier> ProductSupplier { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{      
    public long SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    // navigation property to Product
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSupplier> ProductSupplier { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSupplier
{
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public long SupplierID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }  
}
```

How to insert records on above classes.Will first i need to insert on Product then Supplier then ProductSupplier.

Comment: Are you getting any specific error messages?

Comment: @ Cam Bruce ,thanks for your reply,Looking for syntax how to insert,After a lot of googling get something create object of ProductSupplier,then fill this object property with Supplier and Product object but this always insert on not perform any update.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially just have a M2M with a payload here. With that, you'll need to set the `Product`/`Supplier` on `ProductSupplier` before saving that relationship. So something along these lines:

```
var product = new Product();
var supplier = new Supplier();
var productSupplier = new ProductSupplier
{
    Product = product,
    Supplier = supplier
};
db.ProductSuppliers.Add(productSupplier);
db.SaveChanges();
```

For simplicity, I only dealt with the relationships here. Obviously you'd want to intialize/add the other data on the entities. Also, note that it's only necessary to explicitly add the `ProductSupplier` instance to its `DbSet`. By virtue of being attached to that instance, the `Product` and `Supplier` instances will also be added and saved. You can of course still do that explicitly, instead, if you like.

Comment: ,thanks for your reply.When scenario is insert only then your syntax work perfectly but problem aries when product need to update and supplier need to add or vice versa.

Comment: The nature of `ProductSupplier` is such that it cannot exist without a `Product` and a `Supplier`, so I'm not seeing the issue. Whether the product, supplier or both are new or existing, everything still works the same.